# $R$ a non-unitary ring such that $R^+ \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, rngs

We are given $R$ a **non-unitary ring** such that $R^+ \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. **Prove:** $ab=0$ for all $a,b \in R$.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

We take two arbitrary elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. We can write them as $\frac{k}{r},\frac{k'}{r'}$, with the relations $k=a-rq, k'=b-r'q'$ for some $a,b,r,r',q,q',k,k' \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Multiplying them, we obtain
$$\frac{kk'}{rr'} = \frac{(a-rq)(b-r'q')}{rr'} = \frac{ab}{rr'} - \frac{aq'}{r} - \frac{bq}{r'} + qq' \equiv \frac{ab}{rr'} - \frac{aq'}{r} - \frac{bq}{r'} \in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$$
Since $qq' \in \mathbb{Z}$.

From here, I cannot manage to show that $\frac{kk'}{rr'} \equiv 0$ since the term $\frac{ab}{rr'}$ contains the term $\frac{kk'}{rr'}$. Filling this relation in just ends up giving $0 \equiv -2qq'$, which makes sense since $qq'\in \mathbb{Z}$.

But then I thought more about what $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ looks like, and I am now convinced that it is **equal** to $(-1,1) \subset \mathbb{Q}$. Taking $\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6} \not \equiv 0$. This leads me to believe that the claim to be proven is in fact not true.

I also have the feeling that I should be using the non-unitary-ness of $R$. I read elsewhere that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group that is not isomorphic to the additive group of any ring, so here it must hold because of the non-unitary-ness of $R$.

I am very curious to hear any insights anyone out there might have about this claim, thanks in advance!

EDIT: 20/07/2021 I have marked Mindlack's answer as "accepted" since it is the first one that I understood, and intuitively made the most sense to me. I would have marked tomasz's answer as well if I could, as they provided a general way of looking at this problem and a neat proof. Also check the comments for more!

Comment: What is $R^+{}$?

Comment: @tomasz It is (R,+,0), the additive group of R.

Comment: The question is confusing, leaving us with the impression that a **unitary** ring structure does there exist, which is wrong. In fact, the only ring structure one can endow the abelian group $(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z,+)$ is the one with zero multiplication, that is, $ab=0$ for every $a,b\in \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you for raising this really important point, that should have been the first thing to think of when looking at this question. I may raise that point around the term "non-unitary" with the person who made this question (it is from a collection of notes made by someone at my university). The proof of $ab=0$ is then that posted below by tomasz, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This translates to proving that there is no nonzero bilinear map $\beta: \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. But, if $m,n \geq 1$, $\beta(1/m,1/n)=\beta(n/mn,1/n)=n\beta(1/mn,1/n)=\beta(1/mn,n/n)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I am confused why "This translates to proving that there is no nonzero bilinear map". 

We want to show that ab=0 for all a,b. So having the map $\beta$ that you gave makes sense for this since $\beta(1/m,1/n)=0$ for all $m,n\geq 1$. But the contradiction is that it is equal to 0. So actually the claim "$ab=0$ for all $a,b\in R$ is false. 

Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Btw I would have upvoted but I am not allowed yet.

Comment: A multiplication on a ring is (among others) a bilinear map on its additive group. So if the additive group of $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, the multiplication is mapped to a bilinear function $\beta: \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. I show that $\beta=0$, and thus that the multiplication is zero.

Comment: Got it now! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (both in your solution and the thing that makes you doubt) is that you confound the ring multiplication with the usual multiplication of rational numbers.

The assumption that the ring is non-unitary does not really mean much. In this case, the adjective weakens the definition: usually, every ring is a non-unitary ring, but not every non-unitary ring is a ring (most authors assume that rings are unitary by definition).

$\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ does not *equal* $(-1,1)\cap \mathbf Q$. Every element has a representative there (in fact, it has one in $[0,1)\cap \mathbf Q$, but it does not allow you to define any sort of ring structure.

I think the more general statement is the following: a (non-unitary) ring (in fact, a distributive algebra is enough, you don't need associativity) whose additive group is both divisible and torsion has to be a zero ring (meaning, its multiplication has to be identically zero). I think it's easier, since (by virtue of abstraction) it's harder to confuse the ring elements with rational numbers.

The proof is simple, and a bit similar to what you have written: take any $a,b$. You want to show that $ab=0$. Let $n\in \mathbf N$ be such that $na=0$ and let $b'$ be such that $b=nb'$. Then by distributivity $ab=a(nb')=n(ab')=(na)b'=0$.

Comment: You lost me when wrote "*every ring is a non-unitary ring*". Moreover, the zero ring is quite different from a ring with zero multuplication.

Comment: @user26857: This is how the terms are usually used. A zero ring is not the same as *the* zero ring. The terminology is even less consistent there, which is why I explained what I meant.

Comment: @user26857: Compare: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics).

Comment: Since when Wikipedia is an authoritative source in algebra? But beyond this we have our own judgment and saying that *every ring is non-unitary ring* sounds illogical, at least to me. Moreover, semantic distinctions between **A** zero ring and **THE** zero ring are good for people working in semantics. In mathematics are only confusing. As a matter of fact I suggest you to try explain to a student this "distinction". Maybe will understand it for a moment, but will forget it the next day.

Comment: @tomasz Thanks for pointing out the confusion between the different multiplications. And 10/10 for the general statement you put, and its proof, thank you! As for "Usually, every ring is a non-unitary ring, but not every non-unitary ring is a ring" I will have to really think about this statement, and maybe I will ask a separate question on it. As for the distinction between A zero ring and THE zero ring, I think that A zero ring could be non-unitary, but THE zero ring is unitary, where 0=1.

Comment: @guacamowlie: yes, there are other words for these things. For example, "trivial ring" can also refer to either of those. Regarding the statement about rings vs non-unitary rings, this is not at all complicated: it's just that typically, when people refer to a ring, they mean a unital, distributive and associative (and sometimes commutative) algebra. A non-unital ring is the same, but (possibly!) without the unit. So every ring is a non-unital ring, just the same as every field is a skew field/division ring. The difference between the two is dropping the unit/commutativity axiom.

Comment: @user26857: My experience is that there are no authoritative sources for these sorts of things, only various conventions. Nonsensical as it may be, in my experience this is the most common one. And not a particularly unusual one at that - this is mostly the same with non-commutative geometry, probability etc, where the commutative counterparts are a subcase.

Comment: @tomasz Okay, I see now. So this is another case of the semantics (sort of) of mathematical concepts. Thanks!

Comment: @guacamowlie: Yes, exactly.